# Convert coordinates to decimal degree in Python

Tags: python, pyproj, plotly

I am having coordinates from EPSG:4647, these are e.g.

```
sample_x = 32695710.12
sample_y = 5726463.327
```

In order to plot them on a map (using plotly) I need to convert them into decimal latitude/longitude values. I tried to do the following

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform

inProj = Proj(init='epsg:4647')
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:32632') # WGS84 UTM zone 32

sample_x = 32695710.12
sample_y = 5726463.327

_lat, _lon = transform(inProj, outProj, sample_x, sample_y)
```

But the converted values are - that's not really what I expect..

```
lat: 695710.1199980207
lon: 5726463.3271237025
```

What am I doing wrong?

As per (https://www.pgc.umn.edu/apps/convert/) I would expect

```
lat: 49.320835
lon: 80.065739
```

Comment: Why would you expect lat/lon degrees from EPSG 32632? UTM is in meters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output [EPSG:32632](https://epsg.io/32632) is WGS84/UTM 32N with units in meters.  Try using WG8 84 with units in degrees.

```
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')
```